# What is the difference between those two IP addresses

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to install OpenVPN server on a CentOS machine, the sample configuration files don't make that much sense. Specifically it's server.conf that I find difficult to understand

What is the difference between following two IPs?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local IP address (the IP address that OpenVPN optionally listens on) is the network IP address. So if your office network is 192.168.1.0/24, then you would replace a.b.c.d with an IP address within that subnet range.

The subnet for VPN clients is different. It's a private IP address (range) that ONLY OpenVPN and its clients have access to.

So if you set the server (OpenVPN server) to 10.8.0.0 with a netmask of 255.255.255.0, then you're essentially saying that OpenVPN will hand out IP addresses to its clients within a 10.8.0.0/24 range (255 possible IP addresses after the server gets 10.8.0.1).

Comment: Why is the local IP optional?

Comment: Because typically, OpenVPN listens on a public IP address, not a private IP address. More often than not, you don't need a VPN connection from inside your network - VPN connections almost always come from OUTSIDE your network (on the public-facing internet).

Comment: `Why is the local IP optional?` - Because OpenVPN will bind the socket to the wildcard address by default `0.0.0.0` which means it will accept incoming connections for any valid IP address assigned to the VPN host.  Just try with the option enabled vs no, and look at your `netstat -ntl` output.